# Typescript - Default parameter Type '{}' is not assignable to

Tags: typescript

I've written a simple validation method for a form that takes a `{ [name: string]: string }` object of values in and returns a partial of the same type with error messages, but something about my types isn't working- the Third `E` typed argument is erroring unless I call it `any` with either:

> - `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'E'`. if I give no type information (no `as any`).
> - `Cannot find name 'E'` if I preface `= {}` with the `:E` type
> - `Type expected` if I use `as E`

```
export const requiredFields: <
  T extends { [propName: string]: string },
  K extends keyof T,
  E extends Partial<T>
>(
  fields: K[],
  values: T,
  startingErrors?: E
) => E = (fields, values, startingErrors: E = {}) =>
  reduce(
    fields,
    (acc, fieldName) =>
      values[fieldName].length
        ? acc
        : Object.assign({}, acc, { [fieldName]: "Required" }),
    startingErrors
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will not let you assign object literals to a variable of a generic type. While the generic type constraint specifies a minimum contract for the type, the type could conceivably contain required properties (other than those of `T`) for example. This means that since Typescript can't prove the value is valid for any `E` it will not let you do the assignment.

In your case the simplest solution is to have a public generic signature and a simpler non generic implementation signature.

```
export function requiredFields <
  T extends { [propName: string]: string },
  K extends keyof T,
  E extends Partial<T>
>(
  fields: K[],
  values: T,
  startingErrors?: E
):E
export function requiredFields(fields: string[], values: Record<string, string>, startingErrors: Record<string, string> = {}) :Record<string, string> {
  return reduce(
    fields,
    (acc, fieldName) =>
      values[fieldName].length
        ? acc
        : Object.assign({}, acc, { [fieldName]: "Required" }),
    startingErrors
  )
}

declare function reduce<T, U>(arr: T[], a: (acc: U, e: T) => U, i: U): U;
```